# why findViewById(R.id.wv1) return null Value

Tags: android

i'm try to load some url in WebView (based on user selected menu in navigationbar)
I use a default URL on onCreate and every thing is ok but when i try to load another url based on user secetion, my webview instance return null:

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    /*FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();*/
    /*Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

    mainBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv1);
    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            mainBrowser.loadUrl("http://helpdesk.mydomain.net");
            break;
        case 1:
            mainBrowser.loadUrl("http://attendance.mydomain.net");
            break;
        case 2:
            mainBrowser.loadUrl("http://etime.mydomain.net");
            break;
        case 3:
            mainBrowser.loadUrl("http://mydomain.net");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to do this mainBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv1); code in  onCreate() instead of onNavigationDrawerItemSelected()

Comment: how does your question related to onActivityCreated ?

Comment: you are alright. it is my mistaake in title. i will change it now.

Comment: @Haresh I Initiated mainBrowser in onCreate and everything is ok. but in onNavigationDrawerItemSelected mainBrowser become null;

Comment: can you please post your activity and xml code ?

Comment: @Haresh Code & XML posted

Comment: Oh dear !!! why are post as ans please try post in your question.

Comment: try to remove WebView findViewById code other than onCreate().

Comment: i removed findViewById from other than onCreate and still get same error message

Answer (score 0):

It's good habit if you get your `View` reference in either `onCreate` or `onCreateView` of `Activity` or `Fragment` respectively and make it as global variable scope under that `Activity` or `Fragment`.

Try to shift your `WebView` reference into `onCreate` of Activity(Assuming your are using Activity).

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
WebView mainBrowser;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
 mainBrower = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv1);
}

public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
 switch(position) {
    case 0:
        mainBrowser.loadUrl("http://helpdesk.mydomain.net");
        break;
    case 1:
        mainBrowser.loadUrl("http://attendance.mydomain.net");
        break;
    case 2:
        mainBrowser.loadUrl("http://etime.mydomain.net");
        break;
    case 3:
        mainBrowser.loadUrl("http://mydomain.net");
        break;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the soloution. mainBrowser was null because NavigationDrawerFragment run before on create so i changed code to below and problem solved.

Activity Code:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity
implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {


private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

private CharSequence mTitle;
WebView mainBrowser ;
WebView browser ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
        (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

mainBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv1);
mainBrowser.loadUrl("http://attendance.domain.net");
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
if(mainBrowser  == null)
{
    //Toast.makeText(this, "IsNull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
}
    mainBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv1);
    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            mainBrowser.loadUrl("http://helpdesk.domain.net");
            break;
        case 1:
            mainBrowser.loadUrl("http://attendance.domain.net");
            break;
        case 2:
            mainBrowser.loadUrl("http://etime.domain.net");
            break;
        case 3:
            mainBrowser.loadUrl("http://domain.net");
            break;
    }
}
```